# C# Go to exact instance of class

Tags: c#, class, instance

I have problem with my **ExcelHandler** class:

```
...
class ExcelHandler
    {
        static Excel.Application xlApp;
        static Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        static Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        static object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        static string _filename;

        public ExcelHandler(string filename)
        {
            openExcel(_filename);
        }

        internal static bool openExcel(string filename)
        {
            _filename = filename;
        ... other code ...
        internal Array GetRange(string range)
        {
        Array xlValues;
        string[] rangeSplit = range.Split(':');
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(rangeSplit[0], rangeSplit[1]);
        xlValues = (Array)xlRange.Cells.Value;
        return xlValues;
        }
        ... other code ...
```

If I access Excel files in my code in way:

```
ExcelHandler eh01 = new ExcelHandler(file01); // file for write to
for (blahblah) {  // 1 to 5
  ExcelHandler eh02 = new ExcelHandler(file02);
  Array licLoad = eh02.GetRange("C5:CB5");
  eh02.closeExcel();
  foreach (blahbla) // 26 values
  {
     eh01.insertCell(f.ToString(), row++, 3);
  }
}
eh01.closeExcel();
```

eh02.GetRange returns data from **file01** instead of **file02** and I'm really lost, why? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the `static` modifier from your class members. Your `_filename` field is a `static` field, shared by all instances of `ExcelHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groo's comment is accurate. Creating a static attribute makes all instance of a class share it's value. A static attribute belongs to the type itself, not to the object.

From Microsoft docs:

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx